# Java DataInputStream to image file

Tags: java, image, datainputstream

I am on an homework assignment where I have to connect to a http server and download html files and image files using socket programming.

I am doing fine and is able to download and write both the html and image files correctly. But when I edit the code to meet the requirements of the homework (webpages must work locally, so the code is edited to rewrite the html, the image files are not being written to correctly.

I do not remember editing the code for the method to download the image. I just checked my files when I  thought I was done, and the image showed an invalid image.

The bytes (when i open the correct image and the download image side by side in notepad++), the bytes are the same. The problem is that on the downloaded image, the bytes are written to as one long line, while in the correct image, the bytes are written line by line.

Tried several different methods, and both didnt work. In fact, an old code which I sent to a friend (before the editing above) didnt seem to work either. Any ideas?

```
        DataInputStream imgIn=new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream imgOut = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(host+path)); 
        byte[] byteArr=new byte[1024];

        int bytesRead=0,totalBytesRead=0;

        while (totalBytesRead<imageSize ){

            bytesRead=imgIn.read(byteArr,0,1024);
            totalBytesRead+=bytesRead;
            imgOut.write(byteArr,0,bytesRead);
                imgOut.flush();

        }

       /* while ((bytesRead = imgIn.read(byteArr)) > 0)
        {
          imgOut.write(byteArr, 0, bytesRead);
          imgOut.flush();
        }*/


        imgIn.close();
        imgOut.close();

    }
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I think if that is the requirement : create the webpage locally.

you should not just download the files (htmls, jpegs etc) , you should replicate the directory structure as well, and you would not need to write seperate code to have that work locally.

hope it helps :-)